# How to Open New Tab on Select Tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new in PHP. I want to open new tab when user click on Select Tag Option Value. 
Here is my Code

```
<td> <select name="select_ss" id="select_ss" STYLE="width: 300px"  onchange="open_window(this.value)">
                <option value="">[--Select Sector Study------]</option>
                <?php
                if(is_array($getAllSectorStudys) && !empty($getAllSectorStudys))
                {
                    foreach($getAllSectorStudys as $getAllSectorStudy)
                    {
         echo '<option value="'.$getAllSectorStudy->ID.'" data-href="test.php?id='.$getAllSectorStudy->ID.'">';
                        /*echo '<option value="'.$getAllSectorStudy->ID.'"';
                        echo '>';*/
                        echo $getAllSectorStudy->name;
                        echo '</option>';
                    } 
                }           
                ?>
            </select>
```

And here is JavaScript

```
<script>
function open_window(myid)
{
 $("#select_ss").change(function(){
  var href = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-href');
  window.open(href, '_blank');
})
};

</script>
```

In My code i have an error. When i click first time on Option Tag. Code not working. But i click second time its open new tab. Please help me to remove my error

Comment: Have you tried using `<a href="/test.php...">` tags inside options ?

Comment: yes i tried it but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you put twice the change event :

- Once in your html tag `<select .... onchange="open_window(this.value)>"`
- And once in your js code `$("#select_ss").change(function(){});`

Try removing the one in your js for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have a function that fires, *and* you have an event listener (`.change()`).

Try only using one - for example, adding an event listener when the DOM is ready (using `$(function(){ })`):

```
$(function(){
  $("#select_ss").change(function(){
    var href=$("#select_ss > option:selected").attr("data-href");
    window.open(href,"_blank");
  })
})
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qo89jab/)